# Хранение переменных значение ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть сайт на ASP.NET MVC.  Хостится на reg.ru.
В нем есть переменные, которые хочу вынести для редактирования пользователем (админом), который будет ответственный за этот сайт. К примеру, такие переменные как: почта, пароль к ней, логин/пароль для смс рассылки, которые теоретически могут поменяться и другие переменные. Как лучше реализовать? сделать какой-нибудь файл с разделителями, в котором указать все переменные данные, а в проекте просто читать этот файл каждый раз? Или лучше хранить Web.config ? Если можно в нем, то как это делать и как к этим переменным обращаться?

Конечно думаю правильней будет хранение в БД, но не хочу усложнять + сайт не имеет админской части, соответственно как-то не хочется,чтобы обычный пользователь видел такие данные.

Comment: Просто сделай админскую часть, в любом случае админка пригодится. Это не усложнение, это банальное удобство использования для конечных пользователей и для тебя же в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо! С админкой понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал в web.config:

```
    var email = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email "];        
    var password= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю, в web.config 

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="email" value="111"/>
    <add key ="password" value="222"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Да вообщем-то так